# Django: Keep headers fixed in changelist form

Tags: django, django-admin

Any idea about how to keep the headers fixed when you scroll down in the changelist form?
I have tried with grappelli, and next try will be with xadmin, but I am afraid any skin will not help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a custom [change_list.html template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and custom CSS to give the table header `position:fixed`. Off the top of my head I'm not sure if you can do that to a table row (which is what the header is obv.) so you may need to split that out into a `div`, separate from the table